# How to remove rows from a dataframe based on conditions in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I've been trying to select rows that meet 2 conditions in my dataset, then randomly remove 25% of those rows from my total dataset. I've been doing this with trying to piece together code from similar questions on here but I don't have good python knowledge and can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

I've tried 2 ways:

```
#Store rows meeting conditions in a variable
test = dataset[(dataset['betamax'].isnull()) & (dataset['label'] == "probable")]

#Only select 75% of them in a new variable
test2 = test.sample(frac=.75)

#Remove any matches from test2 in my total dataset
test3 = dataset[~dataset.isin(test2)].dropna()
```

`test2` is 146 rows by 84 columns and `dataset` is 750 rows by 84 columns. When I create `test3` it is 0 rows by 84 columns - why does this happen?

I've also tried to remove the selection of rows by:

```
cond = dataset['Gene'].isin(test2['Gene']) #Gene is my only unique column per row
test4 = dataset.drop(dataset[cond].index, inplace = True)

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Unfortunately I can't give example data, but if I have 2 variables - one where I've subset random rows based on conditions and one which is my total data, how do I remove the subset from my total dataset?

Comment: what's the size of the test  df? Also the dropna might drop more rows that what you want. You should specify the how or at least the columns subset. see -> https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html

Comment: test df is 195 rows, and thank you for this I'll check it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your solution remove `inplace = True`, because it return `None`, so cannot assign to new variable `test4`:

```
test4 = dataset.drop(dataset[cond].index)
```

Better is invert mask by `~` for values not exist in `test2['Gene']`:

```
cond = dataset['Gene'].isin(test2['Gene'])

test4 = dataset[~cond]
```

Answer (score 1):

In your first solution you can use `index`:

```
#Remove any matches from test2 in my total dataset
test3 = dataset[~dataset.index.isin(test2.index)].dropna()
```